# Segmentation Fault 11: 10

Tags: c

I have a problem with solving a problem. I get continue the segmentation fault: 11 error, while I try this code. And every time I change the code the error pops up, and I don't know where the flaw is, so I would be greatfull if anyone sees the flaw.

I thank you in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "dbg.h"

 typedef struct node{
   char *data;
   struct node *next;
} node_t;

 node_t **push(node_t **head, char *data){
   node_t *new_node;
   new_node = malloc(sizeof(node_t));

   new_node->data = data;
   new_node->next = *head;
   *head = new_node;
   free(new_node);

   return head;
}

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     node_t **head;
     char *data = "hoi";
     char *data2 = "hallo";
     head = malloc(20 * sizeof(node_t));
     head = push(head, data);
     head = push(head, data2);
     printf("%s\n",(*head)[1].data);
     free(head);

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you understand what a segfault is caused by? This gets asked like 10 times a day, and the answer is always almost exactly the same.

Comment: You might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: `head = malloc(20 * sizeof(node_t));` does not look correct!!

Comment: Use a debugger! It should then all be obvious. So where is `head` pointing to after `new_node->next = *head;`?

Comment: The overall design is odd: you should not use a pointer to pointer to `node_t`  but just a pointer to `node_t`. And also freeing `new_node` in `push` is totally wrong, you just allocated it and you still need it, so why do you free it ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flaws:

- Your `push()` function assigns the value of `new_node` to `*head`, making it accessible to the invoker of `push()`, but at the end of the function you free `new_node`, making it a dangling pointer. That's a good ground for segmentation faults.
- `head` is a pointer to a pointer but is assigned the result of a `malloc()` invokation that seems to indicate that it should be a pointer to a node.
- Your design is confusing: do you want to allocate the memory in `push()` *or* in `main()`. Certainly, *both* is not a good choice.
- You are pointing to constant strings with non constant pointers. This is dangerous. Writing to the constant strings through these pointers could lead to segmentation faults too.

Here is a version of your program that works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    const char *data;
    struct node *next;
};

static struct node *push(struct node *head, const char *data) {
    struct node *node;
    node = malloc(sizeof *node);

    node->data = data;
    node->next = head;

    return node;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct node *head = NULL;
    const char *data = "hoi";
    const char *data2 = "hallo";
    head = push(head, data);
    head = push(head, data2);
    struct node *node = head;
    while (node) {
        printf("%s\n", node->data);
        node = node->next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that I implemented a LIFO structure, aka. a stack, because a `push()` function usually applies to a stack.

A logical next step for you would be to implement the `pop()` function. Typically, I would recommend that `pop()` frees the node and returns the data. That would provide a nice symmetry for your API.

Comment: When do I need to free the new_node than, because when I don't free it I get memory loss right?

Comment: @John-john, you free it when you don't need it anymore. Up to you to decide when you don't need it anymore.

Comment: @JohnJohn you need to free it once you're done with it, that is once the whole linked list isn't needed any more. What you do here is like buying an ice cream, throw it away, and then trying to eat it.